# React / Express not routing links correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

So, I have a react project that is working fine with the exception of express. I was hard pressed to find MERN stack tutorials on routing with express correctly.

I've found a few SO posts but none work in my project. When I link someone to a react route on express I get 'not found'. I've been messing around with this a fair around hence the commented out static middleware.

```
 Project Structurte

 Root 
      package.json
  Server
       Routes
           index.js
  app.js
  package.json
  Client
       Build
       Public
       Src
```

App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var compression = require('compression')
var session = require('express-session');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var root = require('./routes/root')

var app = express();


app.use(compression({level: 9}))

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
 next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));

app.use('/', root)
app.use('/api', index);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  console.error(err)
  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.send(err.message)
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})


module.exports = app;
```

Root.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('*', function(req,res){ 
    console.log('fire')
       res.sendFile(__dirname, '../../client/build/index.html')
   })
```

React routes in client src

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Home} from './Home'
import {NotFound} from './NotFound'

import {Header} from './Header'
import {Foot} from './Footer'
import {StepOne} from './StepOne'
import {StepTwo} from './StepTwo'
import {Checkout} from './Checkout'
import {SubHead} from './SubHead'
import  {Product} from './Product'

import {Thankyou} from './Thankyou'

export const App = () => (
  <div>

    <Header />
    {/* <SubHead /> */}
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/stepone" component={StepOne} />
        <Route exact path="/steptwo" component={StepTwo} />
        <Route exact path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
        <Route exact path='/thankyou' component={Thankyou} />
        <Route path='/crates/:crate'  component={Product} />
        <Route  component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </main>

    <Foot />

  </div>
)
```

API isn't relevant..

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to export something in root, like adding this to the end of the file:  module.exports = router;

Comment: Ahh, thank you @JeffBreadner. Small oversight. If you add this as an answer, I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that every file you `require()` has a `modules.export`.  In this case, add this to root.js:

```
module.exports = router;
```

Thanks for going through the effort of accepting this as the answer, that's cool ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add react project as a static content to express app.

```
app.use(express.static('client/build)); // path must be relative to your express app

// or if you like to make it work on a sub root
app.use('/reactapp', express.static('client/build'));
```

If you created your project with create-react-app, you should add react projects package.json file proxy for your express app.

```
{
    "proxy": "http://localhost:500" // port can change according to your settings
}
```

There is a detailed tutorial [here](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/). Also create-react-app documentation also includes some information about using it with Node.